# wineprefix is not Initializied correctly

Tags: wine, docker

I m creating a docker image that will install some dependencies and wine to use it after,

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    wine \
    net-tools \
    --no-install-recommends && \
    dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y  \
    wine32 xvfb xauth \
    --no-install-recommends \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I m receiving these errors while running

```
wineboot --init
```

```
11:28:49  wine: created the configuration directory '/home/ipsluser/.wine'

11:28:49  0009:err:file:init_redirects cannot open L"C:\\windows" (c000000f)

11:28:49  0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}

11:28:49  0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}

11:28:49  0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002

11:28:49  0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002

11:28:49  0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
11:28:49  0012:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.

11:28:49  0012:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.

11:28:49  0012:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 183

11:28:49  0012:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0

11:28:49  0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}

11:28:49  0012:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 14007
11:28:49  0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x800736b7

11:28:49  0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 800736b7

11:28:49  0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 800736b7

11:28:49  0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.

11:28:49  0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.

11:28:49  000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.

11:28:49  000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.

11:28:49  Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.

11:28:49  0025:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.

11:28:49  0025:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.

11:28:51  Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.

11:28:51  wine: configuration in '/home/ipsluser/.wine' has been updated.
```

I tried with different versions but still the same, any guidance ?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To make it easier to diagnose your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using. Thanks

Comment: I used multiple versions, same errors.